# Alamofire object mapper: how to parse nested array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

This is my api response:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 24,
            "request_id": "rqst5c130cae6f7609.41056231",
            "business_name": "Code Viable",
            "business_email": "code@viable.com",
            "title": "Load",
            "details": "load",
            "load_description": "load",
            "amount_offered": "1",
            "pickup_address": "load",
            "dropoff_address": "load",
            "timestamp": "2018-12-14 01:51:42"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 27,
            "request_id": "rqst5c1325881836d2.98441728",
            "business_name": "Code Viable",
            "business_email": "code@viable.com",
            "title": "Load",
            "details": "brendan",
            "load_description": "test load for brendan",
            "amount_offered": "1222",
            "pickup_address": "Load",
            "dropoff_address": "Load",
            "timestamp": "2018-12-14 03:37:44"
        }
    ]
]
```

As you can see, it is an array wrapped inside of an array, I have an object mapper setup already for the inner array, like this:

```
struct JobResponseDataObject: Mappable {

    init?(map: Map) {

    }

    var id: Int?
    var requestId: String?
    var businessName: String?
    var businessEmail: String?

    var title: String?
    var details: String?
    var loadDescription: String?
    var amountOffered: String?

    var pickUpAddress: String?
    var dropOffAddress: String?
    var timestamp: String?

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

        id              <- map["id"]
        requestId       <- map["request_id"]
        businessName    <- map["business_name"]
        businessEmail   <- map["business_email"]

        title           <- map["title"]
        details         <- map["details"]
        loadDescription <- map["load_description"]
        amountOffered   <- map["amount_offered"]

        pickUpAddress   <- map["pickup_address"]
        dropOffAddress  <- map["dropoff_address"]
        timestamp       <- map["timestamp"]
    }
}
```

If the parent has a name for it's child array, then I would create another mapper for the top level. But in this case, there is not a name for the outer array, what do I need to do to make the alamofire `.responseArray` call work?

```
Alamofire.request(JOB_REQUEST_BASE_URL, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: nil).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[JobResponseDataObject]>) in


            }
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON object have nested Array. So to parse that you can do it two ways. One way to do this is to parse it as nested array.

```
DataResponse<[[JobResponseDataObject]]>
```

And your code will looks like this.

```
Alamofire.request(JOB_REQUEST_BASE_URL, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: nil).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[JobResponseDataObject]>) in

//...

}
```

**Suggestion:** So far what I can understand from JSON, it should not be in nested Array. If you only need to add one object in nested array, you can achieve same with simple array.

**Second Way**
If you only have one object in nested array. You can also parse it as following.

```
requestId       <- map["0.request_id"]
```

"0." is here to get first object of inner array.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, if I go with the second way approach, do I declare the double bracket in `DataResponse<[[JobResponseDataObject]]>`? if I put the double bracket in, it flags an error

Comment: @BrendonCheung No, You don't have to do this for second way.

Comment: @BrendonCheung share complete JSON.

Comment: the json response? it is in the question

Comment: I think this is not a valid JSON. Please read following link for clarity. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp.